# How to display a datatable when Yes button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

How to display a datatable when Yes button is clicked? In my code the table does not show up.

Here is my code

```
DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to make changes?",
                                       "Context", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
{ 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
    dt.Columns.Add("Temperature");
    dt.Columns.Add("Dimensions");
    dt.Columns.Add("Yield Strength");
    dt.Columns.Add("Weight");
    dt.Columns.Add("Material");
    DataRow _salta = dt.NewRow ();             
}
if (result1 == DialogResult.No)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Now, where do you expect to data to show up?? A DataTable is a non-visual element.

Comment: i want it to pop up when "yes" is clicked

Comment: Lol, it still is a non-visual element. do look into `DataGridView`for simple display of data!#

Comment: thank u, i m sorry for stupid question, it is my first day in coding

Comment: Welcome! This may do what you want: `Form form = new Form();
    DataGridView DGV = new DataGridView();
    DGV.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    DGV.Parent = form;
    DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    DGV.DataSource = dt;
    form.ShowDialog();`

Comment: there is a mistake that i can not find:
                DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Temperature";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Dimensions";
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Yield Strength";
                
                string[] row = new string[] { "1", "2" };
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                row = new string[] { " ", " ", " " };
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                row = new string[] { " ", " ", " " };

Comment: So i tried above code after ur suggestion on DataGridView, but i dont know where i made a mistake

Comment: Your code has a typo: ` DataGridView1` != `dataGridView1` and your rows are emtpy. other than that you can combine it with mine, just adapt the names and (for the time being) comment out the `DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    //DGV.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: i fixed a typo but i still get: 
Error CS0103 The name 'dataGridView1' does not exist in the current context . How can i fix that?i am so sorry for so many questions

Comment: Well you need to create it, don't you think. My code creates one and calls it 'DGV'. When I wrote 'Adapt the names' that's what I meant ,-) I'll be afk for a few hours now; Do let those error messages guide you now, good luck1

Comment: Thank you a lot!You really helped me out

Comment: Added question to body.

Comment: @TaW Could you post your code as an answer please?

Comment: @kame : done, for what it's worth ;-)

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Answer (score 1):

To get a really quick display of the data in your DataTable you can create a form with a `DataGridView`.

Here is an example, which **assumes that you have a filled** `DataTable` and want to show all its data, ie all its columns and rows:

```
Form form = new Form();                // a blank form
DataGridView DGV = new DataGridView(); // a blank DataGridView
DGV.Parent = form;                     // we add the DGV to the from
DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = true;        // to copy all columns from the DataSource
DGV.DataSource = dt;                   // set the datasource to the table
form.Width = 500;                      // some size, change to your needs!
DGV.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;             // the DGV fills the form
        form.ShowDialog();             // we show it as a dialog
```

You should improve on this by at the very least setting the column widths to suitable values:

```
DGV.Columns[0].Width = 40;
DGV.Columns[1].Width = 50;
DGV.Columns[2].Width = 75;
// ..
```

Instead of setting the width indiviually you can also use one of the many automatic modes:

```
DGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
```

Do test them all to see if any one of them works well for you!! (Hint: Sometimes it helps to play a little with the column headers)

In the same way you may want to set some formatting for some columns:

```
DGV.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
DGV.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
DGV.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#00.00°";
```

Note that the numeric format of the last line can only work if the `Column.DataType` in your `DataTable` acutally is a numeric type! To enforce it you can use a line like this:

```
 yourDataTable.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(float);
```

And if it is only for display we should make it read-only:

```
DGV.ReadOnly = true;
```

If instead you want to display it as a means to **edit** the data you will probably need a lot more code; in this case I suggest to **create a dedicated form** and code all the necessary things like validation code, look-ups, proper error messages etc.. Also a `Cancel` button, undo and what not.. This is way beyod the scope of the question, though!

For the simplest editing demands the solution as shown will work, though!

---

Also note that the question as written creates an **empty** `DataTable` with some columns only. Do move the table to class level instead, so you can hold and maybe edit the data!